# Vscode go to definition not working for jinja files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on a flask project which uses lots of Jinja template files and these jinja files contains lot of macros as well

So the problem is if inside a jinja template where I am calling some macro and then I try to `goto definition` of it, it simply does not work and VsCode says "No definition can be found".

So why does vsCode fails to find it definition ? I am heavy user of JetBrains products and with JetBrains IDEs this thing works just great and I can jump to definitions in jinja files as well.